# Why do porn websites link to my site?

Tags: links

I have a website about Bolivia and its tourist destinations. This project is hosted on GoDaddy and has been modified by many different teams. I do not understand why sometimes the most relevant queries are *perfectgirls.net* and other words relating to porn. Why do some porn website have links to my site? It has nothing to do with porn.

My hypothesis is that this is due to some automatic bot crawling the web. Is that right?

Comment: We're going to have to see some example links to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your site has its own unique domain name, you should probably check that these words are not on your site in user comments, a wiki forum or some sort of area where members of the public can introduce or modify content. Maybe you are importing an RSS feed or some sort of external content that may contain those words, including advertising programs or public trackbacks or pingbacks.

I feel it unlikely that your website appears on searches if those terms are not in the site. If that was the case, it would be unusual for those search terms to be the most relevant ones. A couple of years ago this could happen, but, as far as I know, Google changed its algorithms to prevent Google bombing.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to go over your stats. Many websites hotlink images and iframe pages from other websites to make up their content and this results in links to you. These are generally very bad neighbors to have.